# List value is not changing in dart for loop

Tags: for-loop, flutter, dart, indexing

i have list of boolean values i want to change value of perticular index but value is not changing code seems correct

```
      List<bool> toggleTemp = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false];

      for (int k = 0; k < toggleTemp.length; k++) {
        print(k.toString() + " " + i.toString() + " " +  toggleTemp[k].toString());

        if (toggleTemp[k] == i) {
          toggleTemp[k] = true;
        } else {
          toggleTemp[k] = false;
        }

      }
      print(toggleTemp.toString());
```

output

```
I/flutter (32274): 0 1 false
I/flutter (32274): 1 1 false
I/flutter (32274): 2 1 false
I/flutter (32274): 3 1 false
I/flutter (32274): 4 1 false
I/flutter (32274): 5 1 false
I/flutter (32274): 6 1 false
I/flutter (32274): [false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

Comment: Please show the code where your variable ```i``` is assigned or declared. You seem to be comparing an ```integer``` with a ```boolean```. @arjun more

Comment: @RandomGuru Thanks i was comparing int to bool value that's why list was not updating what a stupid mistake But Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to upvote my answer and mark it correct if it helps you. @arjun more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to compare a `boolean` to an `int` which will always not give you `true`.
That is where you error is coming from.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (toggleTemp[k] == i) {
```

is

```
if (false == 1) {
```

so always false.

Answer (score 1):

as per your print statement the value of your variable "i" is declared as an int i.e.,1,  which never be equal to the value of toggleTemp[k] which is boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in your if condition, you are comparing toggleTemp[k] with i.

Where toggleTemp[k] value is bool and false which means 0, so every time condition remain false. as you list contains all false value.

if you want to compare with index then do following condtion.

```
if (k == i) {
```